# Difference between ${"id"} and #{"id"} for getting the object reference?

Tags: java, xml, jsp, mybatis

What is the difference between these two selectors: $("id") and #('id') for getting the object reference in mybatis mapper xml.
I have seen examples like

```
<select id="selectUsers" resultType="map">
  select id, username, hashedPassword
  from some_table
  where id = #{id}
</select>
```

as well as like this

```
 <select id="selectUser" parameterType="User" resultType="User">
  select id, username, hashedPassword
  from some_table
  where id = ${user.id}
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#{id} - MyBatis will generate a `PreparedStatement`
 ${id} - MyBatis will directly inject the value in the statement string

See [String_Substitution](https://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html#String_Substitution) in the MyBatis documentation.